# Why does the event DOMContentReady not happen?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I tried to call a function, when all DOM elements in the page are loaded, like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentReady', function() {alert("good")});
```

It's an HTML file with an empty body and empty head except this JavaScript and nothing happens even if the browser finished loading. What could be wrong here? And are there other ways to do this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's no `DOMContentReady` event.

You want [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded_%28event%29?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOM_event_reference%2FDOMContentLoaded).

---

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {alert("good")});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/JQhjj/

Comment: thank you and sorry for this stupid question. I am new to Javascript and found it on the Google API Documentation http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options.html

Comment: @SaschaMayr You should mark this solution as the correct answer so that user1689607 gets the credit for helping you out with this.

Comment: @SaschaMayr: That may be a custom event they're using.

Comment: @SaschaMayr: Google Chrome Extensions have more/other events than the usual DOM ones. For reference, have a look at Mozilla's MDN (but be sure you don't find XUL-related things) or search the HTML5 draft

Comment: In fact I'm actually trying to create a Google Chrome Extension, I started with just copying the sample code and it didn't work, so I am pretty sure it's a bug in the sample.